Arjun vowing to slain Jayadratha
In the Mahabharata as we know Arjun takes a vow to kill Jayadratha within 1 day when he comes to know about his brave son Abhimanyu's death.
My question is if i am not wrong there are many kauravas involved in killing Abhimanyu on the battlefield which also includes Jayadratha.
Why Arjun takes a vow only against Jayadratha?

Because it was only because of Jayadratha that the Pandavas were unable to enter the Chakravyuha to save Abhimanyu.

Yudhishtira tell Arjuna -


In that battle, we followed Satvati’s brave son. We wished to
penetrate the army through the path that he had followed. O son! But
because of a boon that he had obtained from Rudra, the vile Saindhava,
King Jayadratha, repulsed all of us.


1028 (51), Abhimanyu Vadha parva, Mahabharata.

